# Add content to mysql SELECT field

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm wondering if it's is possible for mysql (and only mysql, no PHP or anything like that) to return an altered field.

See my example.

```
SELECT id, link
FROM table
WHERE link LIKE '%wathever%'
```

It will return

```
 1, www.example.com
 2, stackoverflow.com
 3, google.com
```

But I want it to return the link embedded in an html `<a>` tag

```
 1, <a href='www.example.com'>www.example.com</a>
 2, <a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>www.stackoverflow.com</a>
 3, <a href='www.google.com'>www.google.com</a>
```

Is there a way to do so, like

```
SELECT id, '<a href="'+link+'">'+link+'</a>'
FROM table
WHERE link LIKE '%wathever%'
```

Thank you

** This is supposed to not change the data in database, only in Output, so no UPDATE or REPLACE.

Comment: Use `CONCAT`, something like `concat('<a href=''', link, ...)`

Comment: I knew for group_concat, but never know for concat. It actualy did what I wanted to do. Thank you Jarlh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CONCAT command for this.

```
'<a href="'+link+'">'+link+'</a>'
```

can be emulated by

```
CONCAT('<a href="',link,'">',link,'</a>')
```

to get your desired output. [More on the concat function and its limits and uses.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-concat-function.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can use CONCAT as suggested by @jarlh (I've seen you were unable to do it your self)

```
SELECT id, concat('<a href="',link,'">',link,'</a>')
FROM table
WHERE link LIKE '%whatever%'
```